# Replace NA by 0 by 'x[is.na(x)]=0' replaces whole data frame, not just NAs?

Tags: r, na

I am little bit confused. My **dataframes in a list** **contain** **NA values**, which I would like to **replace by 0**. 
On a single dataframe, I can easily to this by `df[is.na(df)]=0`, and this works well when applied on a single data.frame.
However, when applied on a list ( `lapply(l, function(x) x[is.na(x)]=0)`), **this generates dataframes containing only 0**.

---

Dummy data:

```
df1<-data.frame(class = rep("BO", 3),
                a = c(NA,2,3))
df2<-data.frame(class = rep("BS", 3),
                a = c(5,NA,7))

l<-list(df1, df2)

# Convert NA to 0
l2<-lapply(l, function(x) x[is.na(x)]=0)
```

Results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0
```

But how can I get this?

```
[[1]]
  class  a
1    BO  0
2    BO  2
3    BO  3

[[2]]
  class  a
1    BS  5
2    BS  0
3    BS  7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to return 'x'.  Here, we are only returning the assignment 0.  The dataset is `x` from the lambda function call

```
lapply(l, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0
                       x})
```

---

This can be done in a single statement with a wrapper `replace` (which does the assignment internally and return the 'x'

```
lapply(l, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
```

where `replace` is

```
function (x, list, values) {
   x[list] <- values
   x
 }
```

---

In addition to the `base R`, option, we can do this with `tidyverse` as well

```
library(tidyverse)
map(l, ~ .x %>%
            mutate_all(replace_na, 0))
```

As we are replacing only the numeric column missing values with 0, we can use `mutate_if`

```
map(l, ~ .x %>%
            mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I'll have to remember this fix

Comment: This also works : `lapply(l, function(x) '[<-'(x,is.na(x),value=0))`, or `map(l,~'[<-'(.,is.na(.),value=0))`